# GraphQL: How to prevent nesting attack to gain access to unauthorized data?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, graphql, aws-appsync

I am running an AWS AppSync GraphQL API Service, although the question could equally be applied to apollo-server, based on what I know.

From my understanding of GraphQL resolvers and how they chain, it seems that a malicious authorized client could make an authenticated request against an object they have access to, then chain requests together in the body in order to eventually access records they are not authorized for. **What are one or more effective Design Patterns for protecting against such an attack**?

For an example, I will use a situation that is not my actual one, but should be simple enough to see what I mean. Imagine that we are running a student grades database.

There are types called Students, Grades, and Courses.

For convenience, when you look up a Student, there is a resolver within that returns Grades. Also for convenience, when you look up a Grade, there is a resolver to the Course it was in. Also for convenience, when you look up a Course, you can see the enrolled Students.

Now I, as a student, have every reason to call the following:

```
query {
  getMyRecord {
    name
    studentId
    ssn
    grades {
      gradeValue
      semester
      course {
        name
        courseId
        courseNumber
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This would be a very normal call. Also, the GraphQL API supports methods for course admins and professors too, so they have every right to call something like:

```
query {
  getCourse {
    name
    courseId
    courseNumber
    students {
      studentId
      name
    }
  }
}
```

Again, a very reasonable thing for our GraphQL API to support.

The problem is that a malicious student could examine the schema and decide to extend the first query above to read:

```
query {
  getMyRecord {
    name
    studentId
    ssn
    grades {
      gradeValue
      semester
      course {
        name
        courseId
        courseNumber
        students { #note here!
          name
          ssn
          grades {
            gradeValue
            #... and so on!
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This would result in maliciously beginning to see the grades and ssn's of other students, the courses they are taking, what students are enrolled in THOSE courses, and so on.

I can think of a few design patterns to protect against this, but they all seem inelegant. In particular, I could rerun the authorizer at every single step of a chained resolver, but that will result in a substantially increased workload with lots of duplication of work for 99% of calls.

I very much look forward to learning of established design patterns for protecting against such an attack.

Answer (score 2):

Authorization is handled at the field level in most GraphQL frameworks. You inject the user and/or their roles and permissions into your resolvers through the context object and then include whatever authorization logic inside the resolver itself. Popular libraries like [graphql-shield](https://github.com/maticzav/graphql-shield) can provide a nicer way of doing this and make it easier to create reusable rules -- however, at the end of the day, it's still the same idea.

The key here is that this authorization logic should be applies not just to your root level fields, but also potentially to other fields that represent relationships in your data (like the `students` field in your example).

I don't use AppSync but I believe [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/security-authorization-use-cases.html) describe extensively how to apply this sort of pattern in that context.

The alternative approach is to handle authorization at the domain or storage layer. For example, PostGraphile utilizes row-level security to enforce authorization rules. This can let you implement authorization at the *node* level instead (which resources does the user have access to as opposed to which fields).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which type of authorization you're using, but you may lay on a condition using [context variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-context-reference.html). If you are using **AWS_IAM** or **AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS** authorization, you have `username` from context and you can return a response based on `username`. For instance, in your `students` resolver mapping response, you may have:

```
{
   #if($context.result["username"] == "$context.identity.username")
      $utils.toJson($context.result);
   #end
}
```

If the `username` doesn't match this check, only a null response is returned.